# Is it possible to have my app include itself in the default "UIActivityViewController" share sheet?

Tags: ios, swift

If I were to take a picture with a camera app that uses the "UIActivityViewController" to share content, is it possible to have my app always be included on the share pop over sheet unless specifically excluded?

Twitter, FB, and Instagram popup on the sheet if they're installed without asking the user for consent(as far as I know) so is it possible to have my app always included on that list as well?

Comment: see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivity. What your describing is a share extension. see https://developer.apple.com/app-extensions/

Answer (score 0):

You have to make an application [extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH2-SW2) for adding and handling statement for your application with the `UIActivityViewController` please refer [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionCreation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH5-SW1).

Answer (score 0):

As you need you have to add share extension to your project.
for more detail please reffer 
Link: https://www.appcoda.com/ios8-share-extension-swift/

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by using Action Extension.Follow the given steps

In Xcode->Go to File->New->Target->Select Action Event->Done

Open Plist as Source code, and add the given code.

```
<key>NSExtension</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
    <string>MainInterface</string>
    <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.ui-services</string>
</dict>
```